# How to calculate the limit of $\frac{2^n + (-1)^n}{2^{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}}$ as $n$ goes to infinity?

Tags: limits

I need to know the way and how to calculate the

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{2^n +(-1)^n}{2^{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}}$$

but i'm clueless...

Comment: divide both numerator and denominator by $2^n$

Comment: Write the $n$th term as $$\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}\left(\frac{1+(-1)^n/2^n}{1-(-1)^n/2^{n+1}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{2^{n}+(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}}\right)$$
 $$=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{2^n}{2^{n+1}}\left(\frac{1+\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}}{1+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}}\right)$$
$$=\frac 12\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\frac{1+\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n}{1+\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^{n+1}}\right)$$
$$=\frac 12\left(\frac{1+0}{1+0}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$